# Filter Proper Noun with more than 1 Token with spaCy

Tags: python, spacy

I want to filter out all proper nouns that have more than 1 token from a text file by using spacy. Does anyone have any approach on how to do that?

For example: it would return **New York** and **New Orleans** but not **Mexico**

i only want to use standard libraries and spaCy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly. If you're trying to return proper nouns that are longer than 1 word, like names or cities, run the following code.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
text = "It would return New York City and New Orleans but not Mexico. Some more cities to test are New Dehli, Berlin, Sao Paulo, Buenos Aires, and Moscow."
doc = nlp(text)
pattern = [
    [
        {'POS': 'PROPN', "OP": "!"},
        {'POS': 'PROPN', "DEP": "compound", "OP": "+"}, 
        {'POS': 'PROPN'},
        {'POS': 'PROPN', "OP": "!"},
    ]
]
matcher.add('mutliPropn', pattern)
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    print(doc[start+1:end-1])

# Output:
# New York City
# New Orleans
# New Dehli
# Sao Paulo
# Buenos Aires
```