# Find all consecutive Proper Nouns using only Spacy Matcher patterns

Tags: nlp, spacy

So I came across a question which asked give a list of all consecutive Proper Nouns using Spacy.

Ex: The string "Eiffel Tower, the Great Wall of China, Japan, the New York City, Lionel A Messi Cuccittini" should return:

['Eiffel Tower', 'Great Wall', 'New York City', 'Lionel A Messi Cuccittini']

Below is my approach and the pitfalls:

```py
import Spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc = "Eiffel Tower, the Great Wall of China, Japan, the New York City, Lionel A Messi Cuccittini"
doc = nlp(doc)
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [
    [
        {"POS":"PROPN","DEP":"compound","OP":"+"},
        {"POS":"PROPN","DEP":{"NOT_IN":["compound"]}}
    ]
]
matcher.add("prop2", pattern)
matches = matcher(doc, as_spans=True)
print(matches)
```

Output:

[Eiffel Tower, Great Wall, ***York City***, New York City, ***Messi Cuccittini***, ***A Messi Cuccittini***, Lionel A Messi Cuccittini]

I've tried several ways and this is the best I can do right now.

I tried using IOB tags as well but the IOB tag for "Eiffel" is 'B' but for "New" in "New York City" is 'I' as the Named Entity is "the New York City" with IOB tags BIIO respectively so a generalised approach is not possible. (I wasn't able to find one if it exists).

As I see it, I can only solve this problem if I can somehow get the POS of the previous token to get rid of "York City" and similar sequences. But there's no attribute I can use to get that in the matcher.

The most similar question I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448088/filter-proper-noun-with-more-than-1-token-with-spacy) but the output for this pattern includes the tokens before and after as well:
[Eiffel Tower, Great Wall, ***the Great Wall of***, ***York City***, New York City, ***the New York City,,*** ***Messi Cuccittini***, ***A Messi Cuccittini***, Lionel A Messi Cuccittini]

Is there a way to achieve this?

---

EDIT:

I found we can use greedy = "LONGEST" while adding a pattern to get only the longest match however it messes up the order in which the patterns occur:

```py
matcher.add("prop2", pattern, greedy="LONGEST")
matches = matcher(doc, as_spans=True)
print(matches)
```

Output:

[Lionel A Messi Cuccittini, New York City, Eiffel Tower, Great Wall]

Expected:

[Eiffel Tower, Great Wall, New York City, Lionel A Messi Cuccittini]